# How can i make a div after my navbar take full screen in css?

Tags: html, css, scroll, overflow

Here is the HTML code
I have used bootstrap as well.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    // The code of navbar comes here
</nav>

<div class="main">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 sidebar">
              <div class="sidebar-elements">
                  <ul>
                      <li><a href="#">New Record <i class="fas fa-plus"></i></a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Update <i class="fas fa-pencil"></i></a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Delete <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a></i></li>
                  </ul>
                  <a href="#"> Contact US </a>
              </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

[image: See this picture]

As in the picture there is a black navbar
The violet one is the main class
The one with the background cyan is the sidebar class
I want to make the sidebar and main go full screen.

I added a 100% t html and body. Now if i add height 100% to main class or side bar class then it goes beyond the screen (i guess the height going beyond the screen is equal to the height of the navbar) and adds a scroll bar which i dont want.

Can someone help?

The CSS code is as follows

```
html,body{
    height: 100%;
}
.row{
    width: 100vw;
}
.main{
    background-color: blueviolet;
}
.sidebar{
    background-color: cyan;
}
```

Comment: The way I solve this is to define a height for the navbar and then eighter subtract this height from the sidebar (`.main { height: calc(100vh - 100px); }`) or set all to 100vh and add a padding which corresponds to the height of the main container.

Comment: @Benchy I didnt understand the second way  u said. And also is there anyway which could , make it responsive

Comment: you can try this -> body {min-height: 100vh} .sidebar {min-height: calc(100vh - YOUR_HEADER_HEIGHT)}

Answer (score 0):

As my previous comment was not so clear, I try to precise, what I meant by "add a padding which corresponds to the height of the main container".

```
html,body{
    height: 100%;
}
.row{
    width: 100vw;
    min-height: 100vh;
    padding-top: 100px;
}
.main{
    background-color: blueviolet;
}
.sidebar{ 
    background-color: cyan;
}
.navbar {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100vw;
  position: absolute;
}
```

You have to set a concrete height for the navbar (e.g. 100px). This can be set with responsive class names.

Then you position the navbar absolute and move the rest to the bottom with `padding-top: 100px`. To make this responsive is quiet simple.

That's why I prefer this approach (instead of `calc(100vh - 100px)`).

Be aware that there occur issues with mobile devices when using 100vh. Some browsers change the view height while scrolling which leads to unwanted behaviour for elements at the bottom of the page...